# not finding the path

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my code, I've tried to make a new URL file inside the app and in the main URL file put the function include but I have an error when i run the code, here's my code

the error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index
Using the URLconf defined in f_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^$
^first_app/
The current path, index, didn't match any of these.
```

code for f_project.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from first_app import views, urls



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^$', views.index),
    path(r'^first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),
]
```

code for first_app.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

please, someone help me to solve it

Comment: The path for your index is `first_app/`. Note that you here defined regexes, so you should `re_path` instead of `path`.

Comment: First thing, don't use regex in path, you can use url/repath for that. Second you don't have this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index` url. Your url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/first_app`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `index/` url, but you didn't set that pattern in any of your urls files.

If you want to set that url pattern, you have to do it like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from first_app import views, urls



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^index/', views.index),
    path(r'^first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),
]
```

You are also including another urls file, but it references the same views. Any way, if you set an `index/` url pattern in your first_app urls.py, like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^index/', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

The right url for that pattern would be `first_app/index/`.

In both urls files you are addressing the same view (`first_app.views.index`), so both urls (`index/` and `first_app/index/`) will be exactly the same.

Comment: i did what you've said but i get the same error  .. django don't get the page at any of the urls